# express.static not rendering the CSS file i have attached to html content, i am using Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zVyIK.png) express.static method not rendering CSS file from the public directory, and I am using ubuntu.
but HTML file showing completely without CSS.

Comment: can you display the way you call css files inside html?

Comment: Also please paste your code as text, not image.

Answer (score 0):

replace your express.static line with this piece of code

```
//serve static files
var serveIndex = require('serve-index');
app.use('/public/', serveIndex(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/public/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```